# Why is the loop skipping the last row in my DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I have the following code that loops through a `DataTable` and builds another one if certain conditions are met.  However, the last row in the initial DataTable is being skipped.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++ )
{
    DataRow row = dt.Rows[i];
    DataRow nextRow = i < dt.Rows.Count - 1 ? dt.Rows[i + 1] : null;

    string account = row[1].ToString();
    string nextAccount = "";
    if (nextRow != null)
    {
        nextAccount = nextRow[1].ToString();
    }

    numberOfItems++;
    totalAmount += Convert.ToDecimal(row[2]);
    row[4] = "D";
    row[5] = c;
    row[6] = Sequence;


    if (nextRow != null && i < dt.Rows.Count && account != nextAccount)
    {
        dt2.Rows.Add("N",
            c,
            row[1],
            row[2],
            row[3],
            numberOfItems,
            totalAmount,
            Sequence);

        numberOfItems = 0;
        totalAmount = 0m;
        Sequence++;
    }

}
```

In the above code, if I have a table such as:

```
abc, 1, 2, 3
abc, 1, 2, 5
def, 1, 3, 6
```

It will process both abc's, but not def.

dt2 should contain:

```
abc, 1, 2, 8, 2
def, 1, 3, 6, 1
```

Where 8 is the total for the 4th column in dt and 2 is the number of abc rows.

I am only getting this though

```
abc, 1, 2, 8, 2
```

Comment: define "process" as in you only get rows in dt2 for the first two rows?

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare - Yes, basically dt2 is a summary of dt. I will update my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
if (nextRow != null && i < dt.Rows.Count && account != nextAccount)
```

Try changing it to

```
if (account != nextAccount)
```

I removed:

```
nextRow != null
```

because that prevents the last record from being added.

I also removed:

```
i < dt.Rows.Count
```

because that is already enforced by your `for` loop.

Note: the last row still may not be added if account is the same as the previous row. Not sure what behaviour you wish here.

Answer (score 2):

That's because it appears that the generation of each row is dependent on not only the row in the initial table, but also the row after the corresponding row in the initial table.  The last row doesn't have a "row after it".  The code is written such that it just won't do anything (for that last row), rather than crashing and burning by trying to access a row that doesn't exist.

So looking at what you're actually trying to do I would suggest adapting a solution similar to this:

```
foreach (var group in dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row[0]))
{
    DataRow firstInGroup = group.First();
    dt2.Rows.Add(
        firstInGroup[0],
        firstInGroup[1],
        firstInGroup[2],
        group.Sum(row => row[3] as decimal?));
}
```

You can use `GroupBy` to group the results based on the value in the first column and then generate a new table that aggregates the results of each group appropriately.  Chances are this won't be exactly what you need, but it should get you most of the way there.

Comment: I figured that, but I am not sure how to access the last row to process it.

Comment: @Xaisoft Well, how should it be processed?  It doesn't have a `nextRow` so what should the results be?  It might be worth providing a sample input, what the program currently outputs, and what you would like it to output instead.

Comment: it is in the my question, the initial file has 3 rows and in this example, the second file should produce 2 rows, but is only producing 1.

Comment: Basically, I am just adding up the number of times the first column appears (abc in this case) and once I encounter a new value in the first column (def), I put abc, along with the number of times it occurs in a second DataTable, but once it gets to def, it does not put that in the second DataTable.